# How can I reset Resharpers formatting options?

Tags: resharper

I need to reset Resharpers formatting options to default in order to match the team's settings. However there are other templates, settings etc that I do not wish to reset, as it would take significant time to bring them back.

Is there a way to reset Resharpers formatting settings back to stock, without messing with the other settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper | Manage Options | Select any settings layer | Call the context menu | Reset | Expand **Code Styles** node | Tick **CodeFormatting** checkbox | Hit **OK**

[image: reset settings]